# excel formula for different sheets

Tags: excel, formula, series, sumifs

how can i tell excel to do the formula from sheet 1 to 12; for example:
thats the formula im using now:

```
=SUMIF('[02.09.12]02.09'!C:C, A2, '[02.09.12]02.09'!D:D) +
    SUMIF('[02.09.11]02.09'!C:C, A2, '[02.09.11]02.09'!D:D) +
    SUMIF('[02.09.10]02.09'!C:C, A2, '[02.09.10]02.09'!D:D) +
    SUMIF('[02.09.09]02.09'!C:C, A2, '[02.09.09]02.09'!D:D) +
    SUMIF('[02.09.08]02.09'!C:C, A2, '[02.09.08]02.09'!D:D) +
    SUMIF('[02.09.07]02.09'!C:C, A2, '[02.09.07]02.09'!D:D) +
    SUMIF('[02.09.06]02.09'!C:C, A2, '[02.09.06]02.09'!D:D) +
    SUMIF('[02.09.05]02.09'!C:C, A2, '[02.09.05]02.09'!D:D) +
    SUMIF('[02.09.04]02.09'!C:C, A2, '[02.09.04]02.09'!D:D) +
    SUMIF('[02.09.03]02.09'!C:C, A2, '[02.09.03]02.09'!D:D) +
    SUMIF('[02.09.02]02.09'!C:C, A2, '[02.09.02]02.09'!D:D) +
    SUMIF('[02.09.01]02.09'!C:C, A2, '[02.09.01]02.09'!D:D)
```

is there any way that i can enter 01 in a cell and 12 in another cell and the formula automatically runs?

explained completely.

Comment: So your sheet names are "02.09.01" up to "02.09.12". What's your question?

Comment: I THINK you'd want to investigate the INDIRECT function.  But the information you're providing is not ... explained completely.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the [`REDUCE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reduce-function-42e39910-b345-45f3-84b8-0642b568b7cb), [`LAMBDA`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67), and [`INDIRECT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) functions.

Ultimately, you want to repeat `SUMIF(<SHEET>!C:C,A2,<SHEET>!D:D)` for every sheet, and add up the results.  We can rewrite this portion as a `LAMBDA` function that accepts a starting value and a sheet name, like so:

```
=LAMBDA(val, sht, val+SUMIF(INDIRECT("'" & sht & "'!C:C"), A2, INDIRECT("'" & sht & "'!D:D")))
```

Then you just need to feed it a starting value, and an array of sheet names, using `REDUCE`:  (Which just repeats the `LAMBDA` for every element in the array, and feeds the Output from one Iteration as the Input for the next)

```
=REDUCE(0, {"[02.09.01]02.09", "[02.09.02]02.09", "[02.09.03]02.09"}, LAMBDA(val, sht, val+SUMIF(INDIRECT("'" & sht & "'!C:C"), A2, INDIRECT("'" & sht & "'!D:D"))))
```

However, all of your Sheet Names follow a logical pattern, so… suppose for a moment you set up 2 Named Ranges, called `StartDay` and `EndDay`  (You don't **need** to, you *could* just use normal cell references like `A1` and `B1`)

Then you can combine `INDEX` and `ROW` to dynamically generate an array of sheet names:

```
="[02.09." & TEXT(ROW(INDEX(A:A, StartDay):INDEX(A:A, EndDay)), "00") & "]02.09"
```

And just plug that into your `REDUCE`:

```
=REDUCE(0, "[02.09." & TEXT(ROW(INDEX(A:A, StartDay):INDEX(A:A, EndDay)), "00") & "]02.09", LAMBDA(val, sht, val+SUMIF(INDIRECT("'" & sht & "'!C:C"), A2, INDIRECT("'" & sht & "'!D:D"))))
```